# User Management with Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ansible, user-management

I want to achieve the following user management via Ansible:
I have users named user[1-3], usergroups named admin and developer. And I have a bunch of servers where, based on their usergroup the users should be added OR deleted.

What works so far is adding one single usergroup to a user and adding all users in that usergroup to a specific server group.

Here are my files:

**users.yml:**

```
---
os_groups:
  - name: sudo
    system: yes

os_users:
  - name: userone
    comment: 'Test User'
    usergroups:
      - developer
      - admin
    authorized_keys:
      - key: 'ssh-rsa ...'

  - name: usertwo
    comment: 'Test User 2'
    usergroups:
      - developer
    state: present
    authorized_keys:
      - key: 'ssh-rsa ...'

  - name: userthree
    usergroups:
      - admin
    comment: 'Test User 3'
    authorized_keys:
      - key: 'ssh-rsa ...'
```

**playbook**

```
---
- hosts: testhosts1
  sudo: yes
  vars_files:
    - users.yml

  roles:
    - role: configure-os_users
      usergroup:
        - admin

- hosts: testhosts2
  sudo: yes
  vars_files:
    - users.yml

  roles:
    - role: configure-os_users
      usergroup:
        - admin
        - usergroup1
```

**tasks**

```
- name: Ensure users present
  sudo: yes
  user: >-
    'name={{ item.name }}'
    {% if item.append is defined %}
    'append={{ item.append }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.comment is defined %}
    'comment={{ item.comment }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.createhome is defined %}
    'createhome={{ item.createhome }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.force is defined %}
    'force={{ item.force }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.generate_ssh_key is defined %}
    'generate_ssh_key={{ item.generate_ssh_key }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.group is defined %}
    'group={{ item.group }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.groups is defined %}
    'groups={{ item.groups }}'
    {% else %}
    'groups=sudo'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.home is defined %}
    'home={{ item.home }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.login_class is defined %}
    'login_class={{ item.login_class }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.move_home is defined %}
    'move_home={{ item.move_home }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.non_unique is defined %}
    'non_unique={{ item.non_unique }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.password is defined %}
    'password={{ item.password }}'
    {% else %}
    'password=XXXXX'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.remove is defined %}
    'remove={{ item.remove }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.shell is defined %}
    'shell={{ item.shell }}'
    {% else %}
    'shell=/bin/bash'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.ssh_key_bits is defined %}
    'ssh_key_bits={{ item.ssh_key_bits }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.ssh_key_comment is defined %}
    'ssh_key_comment={{ item.ssh_key_comment }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.ssh_key_file is defined %}
    'ssh_key_file={{ item.ssh_key_file }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.ssh_key_passphrase is defined %}
    'ssh_key_passphrase={{ item.ssh_key_passphrase }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.ssh_key_type is defined %}
    'ssh_key_type={{ item.ssh_key_type }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.state is defined %}
    'state={{ item.state }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.system is defined %}
    'system={{ item.system }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.uid is defined %}
    'uid={{ item.uid }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.update_password is defined %}
    'update_password={{ item.update_password }}'
    {% else %}
    'update_password=on_create'
    {% endif %}
  with_items: os_users
  when: usergroup in item.usergroups
```

I want to be able to use multiple usergroups per user and when I remove a usergroup from that user the user should also be removed from the server.

I've searched the web and Ansible Galaxy forth and back but didn't found anything that could fit.

Do you have an idea how I can proceed? Especially about deleting a User when removed from a usergroup?

I am open to ideas also if there is something out there which is not Ansible but can do the job.

thx,

Answer (score 0):

Well, most places would tell you to use LDAP, but if you want to do it through Ansible - your best bet is to build your variables as subelement lists with conditional flags. So when you're adding "John Doe" with "Group: Team 1" and "Group: Development" and "Group: Special Permissions" - it will associate the proper groups on the servers.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html

The issue is that it's not very maintainable from a playbook perspective. You might want to take a look at LinOTP if you don't already have domain accounts.